# Variable in python script is changing, but when I import the varibale it is every time the same

Tags: python, loops, variables, python-import

I have a two scripts. In one there happens a lot of stuff and there is one variable I am interested in: Called satisfaction
In the other programme I am executing the first several times and each time I have to check, if the value of satisfaction has changed.
But, it imports always the same value for satisfaction, even it changed.
Here is the Code of the second script:

```
for i in range(10):
    subprocess.call('python main.py', shell=True)
    from main import satisfaction
    print('SATISFACTION:',satisfaction)
```

in the first round, it imports the value, but then it do not change it..

First round:

```
Output 1. script: satisfaction:  0.6499999999999999
Output 2. script: SATISFACTION: 0.6499999999999999
```

Second round:

```
Output 1. script: satisfaction:  0.625
Output 2. script: SATISFACTION: 0.6499999999999999
```

Third round:

```
Output 1. script: satisfaction:  0.75
Output 2. script: SATISFACTION: 0.6499999999999999
```

And so on...

I would be really thankfull, if somebody could help me,
Justus

Comment: Why are you calling the script in a subprocess? Just import it once, and repeatedly call it's main function (or something like that).

Comment: BTW, what does `main.py` does? How does the value change in each execution? Does it store it's state in file between executions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to force the reload of the module

```
import importlib 
from main import satisfaction
for i in range(10):
     subprocess.call('python main.py', shell=True)
     importlib.reload('satisfaction')
     print('SATISFACTION:',satisfaction)
```